# Using java to represent a file structure in memory?

Tags: java, indexing, filesystems

I'm trying to index a file structure (not actual data) relative to a specific path on my local disk. Initially I load the file structure to memory then listen for real changes in the directory. If one occurs then I update the relevant indexed files in internal memory. Not unlike what dropbox seems to do?

Does there exist any java-library which can do this? I don't really want to implement this from scratch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To listen for changes on a file, you can have a look at [apache commons io](http://commons.apache.org/io/) which has a [FileAlterationMonitor](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/monitor/FileAlterationMonitor.html).

Comment: I was looking for the method to store the meta-data and manage it. Not how to monitor it. I was using JNotify for that (though FileAlterationMonitor seems good as well).

Comment: @Zoiros My bad, I thought the point was about monitoring file changes. You can have a look at [JBoss VFS](https://github.com/jbossas/jboss-vfs) or [Apache Commons VFS](http://commons.apache.org/vfs/)

Answer (score 2):

Java 7, as part of NIO.2, has the [WatchService API](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javase/nio/#6).

> The WatchService API is designed for applications that need to be notified about file change events.

Comment: I am running on a mac. I'm having truble getting Java 7, let alone NIO.2, to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Zorios - get a different computer for doing your Java development and running Java applications.  Or use a different language for developing Mac applications.